# How to keep track of installed software/sys configuration in linux that I can restore after a fresh linux install?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I have been thinking of writing some sort of utility for Linux that keeps track of all my installed software and configuration. Something that after doing a fresh install I can just run it and will restore my copy of Ubuntu as it used to be before doing the fresh install.

I do not know exactly where to start with this. I know that you can get a list of user installed software from `dpkg -i | grep ii`.

Comment: the `/var/log/apt/history*` files could be of interest.  They include any command used to install/update/remove (parse for `Command:` to find them all).  Keeping track of this, as well as file changes under `/etc` may be enough.   I've been considering doing a mail server set up and feeding the `/etc` directory to a `git` repo to track what changes are actually made... but somewhat leery since usernames/passwords would be included... still could be useful for the class i teach

Answer (score 1):

Debian and it descendants have a tool that allows you to create simple packages (with just dependencies). It is perfect for this job.

It is called `equivs-build` (I have no idea where the name comes from). It will create a `.deb`. You can install it with `gdebi`

Here is a makefile (you can do it manually if you want. The make file only adds 10% of the convenience, but documents the process.)

```
#create source
%.equivs-control: src/%.equivs-control
        @echo %linking "$@" from "$<"
        ln -s -t . "$<"

#make deb
%.deb: %.equivs-control
        @echo %making "$@" from "$<"
        equivs-build "$<"

#install one
.PHONY: %.install
%.install: %.deb
        @echo %installing "$<"
        sudo gdebi "$<"
```

But first you need to install the few tools.

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -fs -T ../equivs src
ln -fs -t . src/makefile

#install what we need
sudo apt-get install equivs gdebi-core make
```

A config file `src/my-packages_1.0_all.equivs-control`

```
Section: local
Priority: optional
#Homepage: https:
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Package: my-packages
Version: 1.0
Maintainer: ctrl-alt-delor@local>

Depends: python3-pystache, equivs, make, gdebi-core, intel-microcode, firmware-linux, multiarch-support, cpufrequtils, openssh-server, stow, etckeeper, ntp, bomstrip, nodejs, dos2unix, faketime, wget, nocache, schedtool, cpulimit, smem, inotify-tools, keepassx, mawk, mmv, yakuake, xdotool, acl, gparted, gufw, htop, sshfs, bindfs, k4dirstat, openssh-client, vim, rsync, emacs, vim, avahi-discover, yaml-mode, markdown, pandoc, dc, xinput, iotop, strace, curl, screen, kdesdk-dolphin-plugins, cvs, easygit, git, git-flow, git-gui, gitg, tig, kdesvn, subversion, hgview, mercurial-common, tortoisehg-nautilus, python-dulwich, task-british-desktop, task-british-kde-desktop, task-desktop, task-english, task-kde-desktop, task-laptop, redshift-plasmoid, gtk2-engines-oxygen, kde-config-gtk-style, kde-config-gtk-style-preview, libreoffice-style-oxygen, appmenu-qt, vlc, konversation, encfs, diffpdf, diffuse, dirdiff, kdiff3, meld, tor, idle3, ipython3-qtconsole, backintime-kde, couchapp, augeas-lenses, augeas-tools, augeas-doc, python3-augeas, sass-elisp, ruby-sass, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-mercurialeclipse, python3-requests, filepp, texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-extra, tth, golang-mode, zenmap, wireshark

# Readme: <README.Debian file; defaults to a generic one>
Description: All of the stuff I want installed.
 This is managed by my install script system.
```

To use:
  - run shell script (this boots this install system)
  - run `make my-packages_1.0_all.install`

Careful if messing with the file names, part is from the `Package: line`, part is built in to the tool.

---

There are other configuration management tools that do a lot more, and are worth a look.

Comment: more info in [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/davids_dad/install/)